# Error for Injected Javascript (Python Web Scraper)

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, traceback

I had a similar problem to this earlier, but I can't figure out why it won't let me click the checkbox. I BELIEVE I am making an error checking the checkbox by selecting it the wrong way.

Here's my traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Sample Programs\Spynner Basic.py", line 19, in <module>
    br.check('input[name="AdvSearchView$SRView$_resultGrid$ctl01$chk"]')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spynner\browser.py", line 846, in check
    self._runjs_on_jquery("check", jscode)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spynner\browser.py", line 394, in _runjs_on_jquery
    raise SpynnerJavascriptError("error on %s: %s" % (name, code))
SpynnerJavascriptError: error on check: jq('input[name="AdvSearchView$SRView$_resultGrid$ctl01$chk"]').attr('checked', true)
```

Here's the HTML/CSS section:

```
<tr>
<td align="left" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: top; background-color: #ffffff; height: 100%">
<table id="AdvSearchView_SRView__resultGrid" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-width:0px;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;" rules="cols">
<tbody>
<tr class="columnheader">
<td align="center" style="width:20px;FONT-SIZE:70%;BORDER-BOTTOM:solid 1px;PADDING-BOTTOM:3px;">
<span title="Select/Deselect All">
<input id="AdvSearchView_SRView__resultGrid_ctl01_chk" type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:ResultGrid.checkUncheckAll('AdvSearchView_SRView__resultGrid', this);"     name="AdvSearchView$SRView$_resultGrid$ctl01$chk"> # THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART I THINK
</span>
</td>
<td align="center" style="width:25px;FONT-SIZE:70%;BORDER-BOTTOM:solid 1px;PADDING-BOTTOM:3px;">Type</td>
<td align="left" style="FONT-SIZE:70%;BORDER-BOTTOM:solid 1px;PADDING-BOTTOM:3px;WHITE-SPACE:NOWRAP;">
<a href="javascript:callback.doCallback('AdvSearchView$SRView$_sortingHeaders','DisplayTicker',null);">Ticker</a>
</td>
<td align="center" style="FONT-SIZE:70%;BORDER-BOTTOM:solid 1px;PADDING-BOTTOM:3px;WHITE-SPACE:NOWRAP;">
<a href="javascript:callback.doCallback('AdvSearchView$SRView$_sortingHeaders','Date',null);">Date</a>
<img style="border-width:0px;" src="/thomson_financial_research_web_ui/3_19/Images/sort_desc.jpg">
</td>
<td align="left" style="FONT-SIZE:70%;BORDER-BOTTOM:solid 1px;PADDING-BOTTOM:3px;">
<a href="javascript:callback.doCallback('AdvSearchView$SRView$_sortingHeaders','Title',null);">Headline    </a>
</td>
<td align="right" style="FONT-SIZE:70%;BORDER-BOTTOM:solid 1px;PADDING-BOTTOM:3px;">
<a href="javascript:callback.doCallback('AdvSearchView$SRView$_sortingHeaders','Pages',null);">Pgs</a>
</td>
<td align="left" style="width:180px;FONT-SIZE:70%;BORDER-BOTTOM:solid 1px;PADDING-BOTTOM:3px;">
<a href="javascript:callback.doCallback('AdvSearchView$SRView$_sortingHeaders','Contributor',null);">Contributor</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

And here is my Python code:

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import print_function
import re
import spynner
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import time
br = spynner.Browser()
br.create_webview()
br.show()
br.set_html_parser("BeautifulSoup")
br.load("https://www.thomsononeim.com/s-log_in.asp")
br.fill("input[name=txtLoginID]", "username")
br.fill("input[name=txtPWD]", "password")
br.click("input[name=Submit]", wait_load=True)
br.click("input[name=Market]", wait_load=True)
br.select('option[value="IBESNA~US"]')
br.click("#MktGoImg", wait_load=True)
br.check('input[name="AdvSearchView$SRView$_resultGrid$ctl01$chk"]')
br.browse()
br.close()
```

Comment: Er, why the downtick? This is a legitimate question, that is novel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this has to do with the name being wrong on the selector.

Comment: Answering you own question?!?!

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I think this is an actual bug. You should report it to Kiorky.
I copied your html to a local document and ran your code (and variations of it).

If you turn on debugging you can see this:

```
Javascript console (undefined:1): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jq
Javascript console (undefined:1): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jq
```

Which makes about no sense at all. This is a spynner defined variable, why wouldn't that exist?

If you try:

```
browser.load('http://www.lehigh.edu/~inwww/form-test.html')
browser.uncheck('input[type=checkbox]')
browser.check('input[type=checkbox]')
```

it works just great.

To get more debug info, do:

```
browser.debug_level = spynner.INFO
```

Check the api or source for what others options of debug level you have.
I might be far off from the truth, so maybe someone else can shed some light on this?

EDIT:

If you add this to the source html source:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

it works. Seems that jquery is not properly injected (which it according to the docs should be).